# how to change <!--more--> behavior in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

When I click "read more" at the bottom of one of my website posts, it just loads the rest of the text in the same page and the same section, thus overflowing elements with text and spoiling my layout. I noticed there is a `<!--more-->` tag at the end of every Wordpress post when Read More is added from the toolbar. How can I override default behavior of this tag so that a new page is opened when a user clicks "Read More..." for a post?
**Update:** 

Post content is loaded from a php file named tazeha.php using jQuery code. 

tazeha.php

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
    <?php 
    require('wp-config.php');
    ?>
</head>
<body>




<?php
            $cat_id=get_cat_ID('تازه ها');
                $posts = get_posts ("cat=$cat_id&posts_per_page=1");
                if ($posts) 
            {
            foreach ($posts as $post):
                setup_postdata($post); ?>
                <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                <?php the_content();?>
                <?php endforeach;
            }
?>


</body>
</html>
```

Can I change the code above so that the text after a post's "" tag opens up in a new browser page (tab)?

Comment: You should post wordpress questions here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks, bu I thought this might be more a php question rather than wordpress.

Comment: We would need to see php code then.

Comment: See [Codex documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_the_Read_More#Link_Jumps_to_More_or_Top_of_Page) for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following a [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18010004/how-to-create-a-single-post-page-in-wordpress-theme), I added a single.php into my theme folder with the code below worked perfect i.e. my full post content is displayed in a new page when I click "read more..." link for any of my posts.
single.php

```
<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">         
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <h3><?php the_category('&nbsp;&rsaquo;&nbsp;'); echo "&nbsp;&rsaquo;&nbsp;"; the_title(); ?></h3>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    </div><!-- #content -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
```